# SML, recursing a datatype array

Tags: recursion, types, sml

I have this datatype

```
datatype json =
    Num of real
    | String of string
    | False
    | True
    | Null
    | Array of json list
    | Object of (string * json) list
```

and this code

```
fun mymatch (jobj,str) = 
    case jobj of
        Array [] => NONE
      | Array(Object oh::[]) => mymatch (Object oh, str)
      | Array (Object oh::ot) => 
           if isSome (assoc(str, oh)) then assoc(str, oh) else mymatch (Array ot, str)
      | Object xs => assoc (str, xs)
      | _ => NONE
```

with this helper function

```
fun assoc (k, ls) =
    case ls of
        [] => NONE
      | (a,b)::[] => if k = a then SOME b else NONE
      | (a,b)::xs => if k = a then SOME b else assoc (k,xs)
```

which should take something like this

```
mymatch (Array [Object [("n", Num (4.0)),("b", True)],Object [("last", Num (4.0)),("foo", True)]],"foo")
```

and return a match on the `string` "foo", searching each `Object` in the `Array`. As you can see in the code, I'm really only handling the two things in `json` that qualify for a match, i.e., an `Array` that contains `Objects`s, then sending the `Object`s to be checked. This code works, but it's surely from the brutalist school of programming, i.e., it feels like a kludge. Why? Because of the case in `mymatch` where I need to recurse down through the `Array`

```
...
| Array (Object oh::ot) => 
     if isSome (assoc(str, oh)) then assoc(str, oh) else mymatch (Array ot, str)
...
```

Until now, I've only dealt with recursion on lists where you check the car, then recurse on the cdr. Again, this code works, but I can sense I'm missing something. I need to check the head `Object` of `Array` and terminate if it matches; otherwise, keep recursing -- all within the `option` return world. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function for matching the "innards" of arrays:

```
fun match_array (str, Object ob :: obs) = (case assoc (str, ob) of
                                               NONE => match_array (str, obs)
                                             | something => something)
  | match_array _ = NONE;
```

then rewrite `mymatch`:

```
fun mymatch (str, Array a) = match_array (str, a)
  | mymatch (str, Object ob) = assoc (str, ob)
  | mymatch _ = NONE;
```

You can also simplify `assoc` a little bit:

```
fun assoc (k, []) = NONE
  | assoc (k, (a,b)::xs) = if k = a then SOME b else assoc (k,xs);
```

Comment: This compartmentalizes, adding better readability, but it seems you have the same problem I had, namely, when you're testing an `Object` how to react if you get a match. Your `...| something => something` would have to be `...| SOME (json) => assoc (str, ob)`. I've put it in a `let val mtest = assoc (str, ob)`, but this doesn't win us much.

Comment: @147pm `something` matches any success from `assoc (str, ob)`. It's not pseudocode to be filled in. (Note that the failure case is first, and that you could also write `SOME o => SOME o`, but that's less efficient.)

Comment: And as I now realize `_` is shorthand for `anything` But `| _ => _ ` doesn't work in this situation. Amazing. Thanks again.